# Rails 3 - best_in_place editing

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, edit, best-in-place

Hopefully a simple answer; I am using the gem [best_in_place](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place) and it works great. I'm trying to figure out how to create a drop down menu using:

```
:type => :select, :collection => []
```

What I want to be able to do is pass in a list of names that have been entered from my user model.

Any thoughts how to do this? Can I mix it with collection_select?

Answer (score 8):

The :collection parameter accepts an array of key/value pairs:

```
    [ [key, value], [key, value], [key, value], ... ]
```

Where the *key* is the **option value** and *value* is the **option text**.

It is best to generate this array in the model corresponding to the object for which you want to generate a list of options for, and not in your view.

Sounds like you have best_in_place up and running, so here's a simple example of a project show page, where you want to use best_in_place to change the assigned user for a particular project with a select box.

```
## CONTROLLER

# GET /projects/1
# GET /projects/1.xml
# GET /projects/1.json
def show
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.xml  { render :xml => @project.to_xml }
    format.json { render :json => @project.as_json }
  end
end


## MODELS

class User
  has_many :projects

  def self.list_user_options 
    User.select("id, name").map {|x| [x.id, x.name] }
  end
end

class Project
  belongs_to :user
end


## VIEW (e.g. show.html.erb)
## excerpt

<p>
  <b>Assigned to:</b>
  <%= best_in_place @project, :user_id, :type => :select, :collection => User::list_user_options %>
</p>

# note :user_id and not :user
```

Note that from memory, the master version of [best_in_place](http://github.com/bernat/best_in_place) sends the ajax request for a select box whether the value is changed or not.

Also something to keep in mind; best_in_place is for "in place" editing of existing records, not creating new ones (for that, use collection_select in your _form partial for the new page).

Comment: Thanks! got this working... easy to miss the code you have at the end of your example thanks to chrome scrolling in OS X.

Comment: Maybe you should select this as your answer if it helped you.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, one question is...how do we allow a 'blank' option to be chosen in the `select`? i.e. either completely `blank` or `none` or something like that.