# Using best_in_place gem how do I specify a nil value for a select tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, best-in-place

The answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589652/rails-3-best-in-place-editing) has provided me with a nice roadmap for how to generate select tags with data from a collection on an association.

This works nicely and everything is going great.

The issue I have now is, how do I handle an empty collection?

With the regular `:type => :input`, I can just specify `:nil => "Some nil message here"`.

But that doesn't seem to work for the collection, and to make matters worse, when there is nothing in the collection it seems to be displaying some integers (i.e. `1` and `2`). I am assuming those are the IDs from the previously displayed objects in the collection, but for obvious reasons that doesn't make much sense.

Any ideas on how I can handle an empty collection with this gem?

Thanks.

**Edit 1:**

One alternative is to just put my original `best_in_place` helper tag inside an `if` statement for when a collection is not nil. But then how does the user edit it when it is blank? Perhaps there may be no way to handle this, because it would involve creating a new record in the collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a "workaround" for the empty options in a select tag, it could help you:

```
:type => :select, :collection => @my_colletion || [[I18n.t('common.none'), -1]]
```

When `@my_colletion` is nil, it shows a choice named 'None' with id = -1 (wich is not that bad to handle in the backend).

This part of code assumes the `@my_collection` is an array of arrays like `[ [key, value], [key, value], ... ]` OR nil.

Although, if you want your `MyModel.all` collection to fit the conditions for best_in_place, you can use the following:

```
@my_collection = MyModel.all.map{ |object| [object.name, object.value] } 
# => this returns an array like [ [key, value], [key, value], ... ]
# => returns an empty array (NOT nil) if there is no entry in the DB
```

**About the -1 id:**
Using the -1 id as 'none' is easy because you don't need to explicitly handle the value nil (tests, etc). With the -1 id, you can use the following:

```
MyModel.where(id: params[:id]).first # => Returns the first object that has the params[:id]
# if params[:id] is -1, it will return nil and not raise an error.
```

I hope it helped :)

Comment: I like this solution. How would I handle the `-1` in the backend?

Comment: Also, out of curiosity, how do you create `@my_collection`? I tried using a regular `ActiveRecord` object, but it needed the whole `[[key, value]]` format that a traditional `@my_collection = MyModel.all` wasn't giving me.